# Arrays comparation in java

Tags: java, arrays

why when i compare two arrays in java the result always appear `false`?

```
package let3;
public class compare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   /////array with array////
        int l[]={5};
        int y[]={5};
        ////compare by == ////
        if (l==y){
            System.out.println("true ==");
        }else{
            System.out.println("false ==");
        }
        ///////compare by equal////
        if (l.equals(y)){
            System.out.println("true equal ");

        }else{
            System.out.println("false equal ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried Arrays.equals(array1,array2); because you can't compare arrays with ==.

Comment: no i don't ,what do that different?

Comment: Thanks ,it work i tried it . but what the jop of (equal) ?

Comment: @Amna97al [Read for yourself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you

Comment: You can use collection methods...list1.equals(list2)